# PHP proxy page with CURL and unkown post variables

Tags: php, post, curl, proxy

I have a page on http://example.com/proxy.php, which uses curl to get the page from http://foo.com/index.php.

I know I can use CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS to post data, but how do I forward the posted data without knowing what Post variables are going to use. So just forwarding all the data that is posted to proxy.php.

So how do I forward all the $_POST data without defining them all one by one?
Also would there be a security risk involved in forwarding all the $_POST without knowing what its forwarding?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean something like:

```
$post = '';
foreach($_POST as $key => $value)
{
    $post .= $key.'='.$value.'&';
}
$post = substr($post, 0, -1);
echo $post; //your string with POST data
```